# keep on getting error after error on my python code

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, python-requests, tkinter-canvas

This is an example of one of the many errors I am facing with currently -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\penguinforce\new code\GUI test 1.py", line 8, in <module>
    geometry("560x280")
NameError: name 'geometry' is not defined
```

Here's the rest of the code from what I can gather from here and the Internet its `tkinter` thats causing me the problems.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

__author__ = 'Sudo'
import Tkinter
root = Tkinter
print Tkinter.__file__
print ("Penguin Force")
geometry("560x280")

import socket
import subprocess
import robotparser
#import requests
import sys
import os

photo = PhotoImage(file="PenguinForce2.gif")
label = Label(root, image=photo)
label.pack()

topFrame = Frame(root)
topFrame.pack()
bottomFrame = Frame(root)
bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

one = Label(root, text="Created by Sudo", bg="blue", fg="white")
one.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

def ScanPort():
    print "-" * 26
    print "Penguin Force Port Scanner"
    print "-" * 26

    Server = raw_input("Please enter a host name or IP address to scan")
    ServerIP = socket.gethostbyname(Server)
    Firstport =int(input("Start scanning from this port"))
    SecondPort = int(input("To this port"))

    print "-" * 80
    print "Please wait, we are currently scanning IP/Host for all ports available", ServerIP
    print "-" * 80

    try:
        for port in range(Firstport, SecondPort):
            sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            result = sock.connect_ex((ServerIP, port))
            if result == 0:
                print "Port {}: \t Open".format(port)
            else:
                print "Port {}: \t closed".format(port)
            sock.close()

    except socket.error:
        print "Couldn't connect to IP/Host!"
        sys.exit()

    except socket.gaierror:
        print "Hostname could not be resolved. Exiting"
        sys.exit()

def CrackHouse():
    for item in range (999):
        params = {"username":"JoeSmith", "password":item}
        r = requests.get("http://creative.coventry.ac.uk/eh/web_ch4/welcome.php",
                         params = params)
        if r.text.find("incorrect") >=0:
            print "Fails on {0}".format(item)
        else:
            print "Passcode {0} Ok".format(item)
            return item

def ListRestricted():
    sites = ['www.google.com','www.coventry.ac.uk', 'www.yahoo.com']

    def getDenies(site):
        paths =[]
        robot = robotparser.RobotFileParser()
        robot.set_url("http://"+site+"/robots.txt")
        robot.read()

        for line in robot.default_entry.rulelines:
                not line.allowance and paths.append(line.path)
        return set(paths)

    for site in sites:
        print "Denies for " +site
        print "\t" + "\n\t".join(getDenies(site))

def create_contract(self):
    name = self.name_entry.get()
    address = self.address_entry.get()

def identifyOUI(macaddress):
    database = open("data.txt", "r")
    for line in database:
        if macaddress in line: print line
    database.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    identifyOUI("A4:18:75")


def GenerateReport():
    ListRestricted()
    print ScanPort()
    print CrackHouse()
    print identifyOUI()
    print ListRestricted()
    print ("Documentation generated and saved to file.")

button1 = Button(topFrame, text = "Scan Port", fg="blue", command=ScanPort)
button2 = Button(topFrame, text = "Crack House", fg="blue", command=CrackHouse)
button3 = Button(topFrame, text = "List Restricted", fg="blue", command=ListRestricted)
button4 = Button(topFrame, text = "identifyOUI", fg="blue", command=identifyOUI)
button5 = Button(topFrame, text = "Generate Report (not functional)", fg="blue", command=GenerateReport)

root.rowconfigure((0,1), weight=1)
root.columnconfigure((0,2), weight=1)

button1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan= 500, sticky = 'EWNS')
button2.grid(row = 1, column = 1, columnspan= 500, sticky = 'EWNS')
button3.grid(row = 2, column = 2, columnspan= 500, sticky = 'EWNS')
button4.grid(row = 3, column = 3, columnspan= 500, sticky = 'EWNS')
button5.grid(row = 4, column = 4, columnspan= 500, sticky = 'EWNS')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `geometry` is a method belonging to the `Tk` class. You have to do something like `my_tk_instance.geometry("560x280")`. Also, `root = Tkinter` will almost certainly not do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

geometry cannot be accessed directly, you would have to create an object of button or what ever you try to have and store it in a variable called fred or your choice. then you can have the setting like this fred["geometry"] = "560x280". I hope this is some help to you.

Answer (score 0):

root should be

root = Tkinter.Tk()

root.geometry("560x280")

Answer (score -1):

As the error indicates, `geometry` is not defined. Did you intend to import it from somewhere?